Повтор предлога: правильно ли сформулировано предложение?

Совершая авторизацию, вы соглашаетесь с обработкой персональных
данных, политикой обработки ПДн, правилами работы сервиса.

Вопрос: нужно ли ставить предлог «с» перед словами «политикой» и «правилами»? Или возможны оба варианта?

Почитал все ответы и комментарии, даже по ссылкам перешёл. Ну... у нас как всегда :) Так и хочется произнести банальное «Ребята, давайте жить дружно». А для новичков вообще трудно понять, кто кому на что отвечает — надо смотреть время.
Исходное предложение, извините, никуда не годится:

Повтор слова «обработка» и вдобавок однокоренное «работа».
Сначала «персональные данные», и тут же какое-то «ПДн». Что это за аббревиатура?! Пользователь, конечно, догадается (но не сразу), а может, всё-таки захочет уточнить... Зачем эти сложности, навороты и опять же повторы? Для «солидности»? И зачем эта добавка в виде маленькой «н»? Что она показывает?
Сообщение/оповещение должно быть ёмким, по возможности кратким, без лишних  загадочных отсылок.

Не знаю... мне часто предлагают согласиться/ознакомиться с политикой конфиденциальности, и если уж без этой политики никак, то мой вариант такой (не претендую на совершенство или оригинальность, а повтор предлога опционален, но в данном случае, считаю, избыточен, так как падеж ясно даёт понять, что к чему):
Совершая авторизацию, вы соглашаетесь с обработкой персональных данных, политикой конфиденциальности и правилами сервиса.
И вот первый попавшийся сайт, на котором доступно написано, «что такое политика конфиденциальности и как ее составить» (UNISENDER):

Политика конфиденциальности — документ, который обязаны размещать у себя на сайте все, кто собирают и обрабатывают персональные данные пользователей.
<...>
Персональные данные — это любая информация о пользователе, которая помогает его опознать.
<...>
А политика конфиденциальности — это документ, в котором оператор рассказывает, как и зачем он использует персональные данные своих субъектов (пользователей).
Кстати, политику конфиденциальности могут называть по-разному:

пользовательское соглашение,
положение об обработке персональных данных,
политика обработки данных для сайта,
политика приватности,
политика защиты персональных данных,
privacy policy.


P. S. Наталья, на этом сайте принято отмечать все полезные ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из них галочкой, как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему. (И поучаствуйте, пожалуйста, в дискуссии — вон сколько всего понаписано.)

Мне нравится ваш вариант записи,  голос от меня.  Изящество и простота, которая должна быть в каждой вещи. ПДн — терминологическая аббревиатура, она встречается в специальных документах, но нужно отличать от ПДН (подразделение по делам несовершеннолетних). Но в такой записи, обращенной к обычным пользователям, действительно неуместна.

@Sharon Спасибо, Sharon, проголосовал за вас, сразу не хотел только из-за самого предложения (вы ведь часто редактируете исходники).

● Думаю, что предложение лучше оформить таким образом:
Совершая авторизацию, вы соглашаетесь с обработкой персональных данных и с правилами работы сервиса.
• Почему с двумя предлогами?
Потому что каждое из дополнений является распространенным и сами понятия "обработка" и "правила" не близки по смыслу (их желательно подчеркнуть, разграничить).
Вот рекомендации Н. Н. Кохтева и  Д. Э. Розенталя (§ 54. Предлоги при однородных членах предложения):

Одинаково возможны сочетания однородных членов с наличием предлога только перед первым из них (например: бывать у родственников, друзей, знакомых) и с повторением предлога перед каждым однородным членом (например: бывать у родственников, у друзей, у знакомых).
Предлог повторяется: <...>
в) если однородные члены сильно распространены пояснительными словами, например: Пыль толстым слоем лежала на письменном столе, обитом зелёным сукном, на широком диване с удобной спинкой, на старом кожаном кресле.

Вот мнение Л. В. Рахманина (§ 44. Трудности в употреблении предлогов при однородных членах предложения):

Предлоги могут повторяться перед каждым однородным членом предложения (для большего логического выделения каждого слова в ряду перечисления), могут и не повторяться (если подчёркивается смысловая и грамматическая близость однородных членов). Например: По долинам и по взгорьям шла дивизия вперёд; но: На улицах и площадях — всюду празднично одетые люди. <...>
Предлоги повторяются и в том случае, когда однородные члены распространены зависимыми словами.

• Почему без политики обработки ПДн?
Раз уж мы согласились собственно с обработкой данных, то придется смириться и с любой политикой этой самой обработки (значения она уже не имеет).
• О сокращении
Вот здесь — ПД.
Вот здесь — и ПД, и ПДн.
Вот здесь — ПДн.
А вот тут — ПнД.
Похоже, что на сегодня единообразия в написании нет.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Дополнительный ответ
В приведенном предложении связь бессоюзная и нет явных признаков для 
однозначного решения...

Конечно же, эти признаки есть — это распространенность однородных дополнений и логическое выделение. (Об этом сказано в моем первом ответе; приведены рекомендации известных авторов.)
Не мешает почитать статью:

Слушаюсь! Почитала.
Сделанные собственные логические выводы от этого пока не поменялись.
Но даже если я не права в своих рассуждениях (об обработке и о политике обработки), то в первичном предложении, имеющем официально-деловой стиль, считаю, нужно поставить все три "с".
Наличие предлога у каждого дополнения позволяет четко выделить каждую позицию, на которую кто-то, совершая авторизацию, соглашается.
Предварительная консультация с автором также не помешает.

В этом нет нужды. Предложение (с вариациями) имеется в Google.
Совершая авторизацию, вы соглашаетесь...

Кстати, вы зря вы не отвечаете на мои комментарии. Можно было бы все выяснить без множества ответов и лишнего информационного шума.

• Нужное из источников надо переписывать (Вы сами так делаете), потому что часто со временем ссылки не открываются. • Я не говорила, что статья мне понравилась. Наоборот. • Деловой язык редко бывает красивым. • Критика — это, конечно, здорово! В разумных пределах — не удушающе, не навязчиво, не оскорбительно, не с чувством собственного превосходства (дайте! объясните! убедите! делаю вам замечание). Чего же потом удивляться тому, что мало отвечающих. • Прежде чем критиковать, Вы хоть свой-то ответ исправьте. (А Вашу правку шапки я уже изменила.)

Да ладно, я сама скромность,  тише воды)  И работаю, аки пчела.  И превосходства никакого, уверяю вас. У меня очень низкая самооценка.  давайте не будем такими серьезными,  того не стоит. // И мне очень хочется отдохнуть, а все никак не получается, каждый раз что-то мешает. Вот уж отдохнете от меня))

@Sharon Не отдыхайте, пожалуйста. Без вас здесь никак :)

Спасибо!  Но я здесь уже почти год, а это много.  К этому времени мои ответы начинают казаться "высокомерными")))

Sharon, она Вам не отвечает как раз во избежание таких ненужных наездов и споров. P. S. А мое мнение о Ваших знаниях тем не менее не изменилось, они, повторю, — безграничны.

Оставим ненужное... Но — о предлогах говорится все-таки в § 207.

Да ладно, мелочные недочеты, цитирую я верный параграф. Мой ответ  в принципе правильный: три однородных   члена, нет повтора предлога.  И комментарий вполне обоснованный: почему убрали  3-й однородный член из авторского текста?  А в результате целая конференция по поводу одного комментария, оставшегося без ответа. А теперь еще и обоснование: во избежание ненужных наездов и споров. Часто ли я вообще пишу вам комментарии,  да и вообще как-то вас упоминаю при ответах. Это уж точно во избежание.

Возможны оба варианта. Относительно политики и правил: если слова стоят в начале названий документов, они должны писаться с прописной. Относительно обработки и политики обработки. Не является ли одно уточнением или продолжением другого? Если так, то второе, наверное, можно убрать в скобки.

Насчёт прописных – да, видел такое оформление.

Я бы записала так:
Совершая авторизацию, вы соглашаетесь с обработкой персональных данных, политикой обработки ПДн и правилами работы сервиса.
Пояснение

Тема регулируется правилами Розенталя §206. Предлоги при однородных членах
Предлог, стоящий перед первым однородным членом, может 
опускаться перед остальными однородными членами, но может 
и повторяться перед каждым из них. Ср.: Хозяин, из 
почтения и радости, ничего не ел... (Пушкин). – Феничка 
вся покраснела от смущения и от радости (Тургенев).


В приведенном предложении связь бессоюзная и нет явных признаков для однозначного решения, но на слух предложение не совсем корректно. Поэтому приходится искать какой-то компромисс относительно повтора предлогов.


О записи ПДн
Вероятно, это специальная терминология
  Защита ПДн 

 ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ БЕЗОПАСНОСТИ ОБРАБОТКИ ПЕРСОНАЛЬНЫХ ДАННЫХ 

 Осуществление мероприятий по защите персональных данных 
 является обязательным в силу требований федерального закона 
 от 27 июля 2006 г. № 152-ФЗ «О персональных данных» и 
 постановления Правительства Российской Федерации от 17 
 ноября 2007 г. № 781 "Об утверждении Положения об 
 обеспечении безопасности персональных данных при их 
 обработке в информационных системах персональных данных". 


Дополнение к первому ответу с последующим переосмыслением комментариев
«Как наверху, так и внизу; как внутри, так и 
снаружи».  Принцип соответствия Гермеса 
Трисмегиста устанавливает аналогию между 
макрокосмом и микрокосмом. 

Иногда в самых малых вещах можно увидеть отражение значительного и масштабного. И чем мельче событие, тем яснее может быть видна эта общая картина мира. Так было и будет всегда?
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/2917971335252384527
А это вообще впечатляет (из комментариев):
УМНЫЙ ЧЕЛОВЕК ВАМ СКАЗАЛ, ЧТО ТРЕТИЙ ЧЛЕН НЕ НУЖЕН, ЗНАЧИТ НЕ НУЖЕН.
  Почему без политики обработки ПДн?
  Раз уж мы согласились собственно с обработкой 
  данных, то придется смириться и с любой политикой 
  этой самой обработки (значения она уже не имеет). 
  (Из предложенного ответа.)


Не могу согласиться с тем, что не нужен.  Политика обработки данных может быть разной и даже индивидуальной, хотя есть и общие законы. На каждом ресурсе определенная политика, вот с ней и нужно согласиться.  Эта часть фразы является обязательной.

Не мешает почитать статью или любой другой материал про ПДн. Там обсуждается вопрос: "Политика обработки, согласие на обработку, положение о персональных данных". И ясно видно, что ПДн – это отдельная тема: должно быть указано, как используются персональные данные и как они защищены.

Поэтому не стоит  делать собственные логические выводы о содержании заданного вопроса, особенно если текст касается специальных тем. Предварительная консультация с автором также не помешает.


И вывод: третий член нужен! Задача должна решаться относительно повтора предлога  для трех однородных членов.
