Грамматическая ошибка или допустимый вариант
Должен ли был повториться предлог "по" перед вторым однородным членом "притоку" или высказывание может существовать и в таком виде?

В этом году решались задачи по привлечению новых
высококвалифицированных кадров, притоку талантливой молодежи, по
повышению квалификации сотрудников, по укреплению взаимодействий
исследователей для разработки идей.


В качестве варианта:
В этом году решались задачи по привлечению новых высококвалифицированных кадров и  притоку талантливой молодежи, по повышению квалификации сотрудников, по укреплению взаимодействий исследователей для разработки идей.
§207. Предлоги при однородных членах
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480939/Повтор-предлога-правильно-ли-сформулировано-предложение/480955#480955

То есть исходный вариант имеет место быть?

Да, предлог не обязан повторяться. Здесь бессоюзная связь, поэтому выбор есть. Но повтор четырех предлогов мне представляется лишним, поэтому я объединила два близких члена союзом И.  Так лучше звучит, чем при отсутствии предлога. Это стилистическая грамматика,  выбор на усмотрение автора с учетом правила Розенталя.

Я просто помню правило о том, что предлог должен повториться либо перед каждым о.ч., либо только перед первым.

Вот пример у Розенталя: За нею с кувшином, медным тазом, с простынями и губкой шла ее кухарка Ольга (Чехов). Разные варианты при комбинировании. Возможно, использование союза И корректирует общее правило.  Мне второй член без предлога и союза И на слух не нравится. Но это именно стиль речи.

В этом году решались задачи по привлечению новых высококвалифицированных кадров, по притоку талантливой молодежи, по повышению квалификации сотрудников, по укреплению взаимодействий исследователей для разработки идей.
Пусть будет равное количество предлогов - два-то уже даны.

Галина. Спасибо за ответ. Но ошибка ли, если предлога нет? Допускает ли русский язык?

Асимметрия наблюдается, но это не грамматика. Допускает.

С точки зрения грамматики ничто не мешает сказать, что привлечение и приток это два однородных. И что "по привлечению... притоку..." и "по повышению" тоже два однородных.
Как например в предложении:

В этом году решались задачи по привлечению новых
высококвалифицированных кадров и притоку талантливой молодежи, по
повышению квалификации сотрудников, по укреплению взаимодействий
исследователей для разработки идей.

Также никто не мешает сказать, что предлог просто кое-где опущен, типа он есть но опущен.
Дождь прошел по полям, лесам...по озерам и траве, по крыше, по речке.... оврагам и по горам.
